# Is there a way to set search_path for Zend_Db connection?

Tags: postgresql, pdo, zend-db

I have a Postgres database with tables spread across multiple schemas. I have a ton of pre-existing models for those tables which do not specify schema name(initial design was to keep all table under single schema)

Is there a way to define a custom search_path for a Zend_Db connection with PDO_PGSQL being the driver?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ALTER ROLE foo SET search_path = bar, baz;
```

where `foo` is the database user name you use.  (Repeat for other user names if necessary.)